# what is the difference of head and single-term pattern in racket?

Tags: racket

Can any one tell me what is the difference between head and single-term pattern in racket?how it helps to differentiate the Typed and Untyped Racket code?

Comment: I can't speak to how these terms are related to Racket specifically, but there exists a common pattern in many Lisps's macro systems where a pattern is broken down into its `head` and `tail`, the `head` being a variable bound to the first term and the `tail` being the list of all remaining terms.

Comment: thank u for ur comment @zv_